# Call a closure recursively

Tags: ios, swift, recursion, closures

In a chat app I'm working on, I need to send the phone numbers taken from the Contacts to an API and retrieve the numbers that have already registered with the app.

Since contact lists can be very long, I'm planning to send the phone numbers in batches (20 per request). And update the UI according to every returned response.

```
private(set) var registeredContacts: [RegContact] = []

let phoneNumbersInBatches: [[String]] = [[]]

for batch in phoneNumbersInBatches {
    ApiClient.sharedInstance.getRegisteredContacts(from: batch) { contacts, error in
        // Saving to database
        // Update the UI
        // ...

        self.registeredContacts += contacts
    }
}
```

I want to send each batch one after the other. In other words, here's how I want the process to go.

> Send batch -> get response -> update the UI (if there are registered users) -> Send next batch -> ...

But with `getRegisteredContacts` being a closure, the `for` loop just sends all the requests out one after the other without waiting for the previous request to be completed.

How can I make it wait and fire each subsequent request once the previous request is completed?

Comment: Synchronous is rarely a good idea. You should look at NSOperationQueue.

Answer (score 0):

If I got it correctly, you want something like this:

```
sendNumbers(allNumbers)

func sendNumbers(_ numbers:[], fromOffset offset: Int = 0) {
    ApiClient.sharedInstance.getRegisteredContacts(from: batch) { contacts, error in
        // Saving to database
        // Update the UI
        // ...

        self.registeredContacts += contacts
        offset += myValueForExample20
        sendNumbers(numbers, fromOffset: offset)
    }
}
```